# Mapply filter function over two lists with group by

Tags: r, mapply

I have the following data (simplified):

```
data1 <-  data.frame(cool_A = c(5,10,15,20, 5,10,15,20),
                    cool_B = c(10,20,25,30, 10,20,25,30),
                    group = c('group1','group1','group1','group1','group2','group2','group2','group2'))

data2 <- data.frame(A = c(0.2),
                    B = c(0.5))
```

I am attempting to run the stats filter function over the data like so:

```
function2 <- function(x, y) {as.numeric(stats::filter(x, filter=y, method="recursive"))}
test2 <- mapply(function2, data1[,c(grep("^cool", names(data1)))], data2)
test2
```

This works to a certain degree, but I would like to group/split the filter function by 'group' in data1. My idea was to split data1 into a list and apply it to the function but this doesn't work. I have also tried working a 'by' function into the code. Any suggestions?

```
data1b <- split(data1, data1$group)

test2 <- mapply(function2, data1b[,c(grep("^cool", names(data1b)))], data2)
test2
```

Comment: `lapply(data1b, function(x) mapply(f, x[...], data2))`? Usually after using `split`, you'll do `lapply`.

Comment: Works great, thanks!